# Distributing with Boost Library?

Tags: c++, boost, distribution

I'm quite new to using boost and I can't seem to find documentation anywhere on how to distribute your application when using boost?

Many of the libraries are shared libraries, I'm not expecting my users to have boost installed, I'm only using a single library (regex) so is there an easy way to package the regex library with my application without compiling with the static version?

Comment: I want to distribute for linux and in the future for windows.

I will also keep it open sourced so I will provide the source code for users to build as well as pre-built binaries

Comment: If you're using only regex, there's a high chance that your compiler already support regex through TR1. Try #include <regex>.

Comment: yeah thats one of the reason for choosing it instead of the other regex library that doesn't need buildling. Although i didn't want to take gamble if the TR1 isn't fully supported by all compilers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Linux

For binary distribution, I recommend using the distribution's package management, which should take care of any dependencies.
Some commercial apps just use binary blobs and you need to install a version of boost by yourself.

Finding libraries is a bit more difficult on linux. It does not automatically load shared objects from the current directory if they are linked at compile time (as opposed to loading at runtime with dlopen).

You have to use the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable or use [rpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath_(linking)). Both has it's drawbacks.

### Windows

There is no way around including the dlls. The usual approach is to put everything into a directory and zip it up.

### Both

To build from source you need the boost sources anyway, so no need to include libraries.

Most libraries in boost are header only anyway, regexp is not one of them. It should be sufficient to include dlls for this module.
In Linux you can check against which shared libs your binary is compiled by using:

```
ldd binary
```

Comment: Yeah I was intending to just provide the .so and .dll files for pre-built applications seperate from source. So your saying it will work just by taking the the compiled lib files? With the regex I know like u said its not a header only file, so I will provide the built regex library with the source as well

Comment: Compiled lib files? Users need all linked shared libraries. For Linux you should rely on the package management.

Comment: sorry i meant providing the pre-built regex library instead of relying on the user to have it built. With the source code version I don't have to worry, i'll let the user take responsibility to get the appropriate libraries should they want to build it.

If all works just by providing the .so or .dll files then its good. I heard boost had a tool where it can extract and find all libraries your app is using, anyone know?

Comment: So what do you want know? It is possible to provide .so files. Is it good style? Probably not, you should use package management for libs.

Comment: well what if i said what i'm creating is a shared library? So i'm trying to find a way to distribute my library that also uses a bit of another library... lol. I'm a bit lost on how to distribute it with these dependencies

Comment: On Linux, one can indeed rely on the package manager, but **what if the Linux distribution comes with an outdated Boost version** and you need newer features? In this scenario, the question of distributing parts of Boost (rather than relying on the package manager) makes sense.